# Updating cloned elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have text input A.  I create a new form element, F, in javascript, but do not attach it to the DOM.  I then attach an input B (clone of input A) to F.  Input B is supposed to mimic input A so I'll use an event listener to change the value of B based on the events of A.  This "updates" input B based on input A.  However, what if I'm not dealing with inputs or the "value" attribute?  Is there a general way of updating clone elements to mimic original elements? (Preferably without the use of jQuery, Dojo, or other libraries)

For example what if I wanted to clone and mimic a select element or something more complex?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's directly possible. For example, do you want to have select #2 opened as well when select #1 is being opened by the user? I doubt whether such things are possible at all.

Comment: I'm not really focus on the ui of the elements, but mostly just the values.  So the select element should mimic the original in the sense of with option is selected, what options there are, etc.  I don't really care about mimicing mouse clicks, when dropdown boxes drop, etc

Answer (score 0):

Brute force approach:

Use a setInterval() to periodically duplicate all the attributes to your mimic element.